# stop google indexing php page that redirects

Tags: php, indexing, meta, noindex

I have a (randomly named) php file that does a bit of processing and then uses a header("location:url") to redirect to another page.

As mentioned, the script has a random name (eg: euu238843a.php) for security reasons as I don't want people stumbling upon it.

Thing is - How do I stop Google from indexing it - I want other pages in the same directory to be indexed but not this php file.  I don't want people to be able to do a site:myurl.com and find the "hidden" script.

I would normally put a  meta name="robots" content="noindex" in the head but, I can't do that as the page needs to ouput headers at the end to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically updated the robots.txt file within the directory using a PHP script that outputs a new or appended `robots.txt` as needed. If you specify each dynamic filename on a new line, such as `Disallow: /File_12345.html`, you can avoid having to disallow the entire directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - That would work but my only concern is that anyone with a bit of knowledge would be able to read robots.txt and then instantly see the names of the files I don't want them to find.